# Apply multiple numeric formatting simultaneously, C#

Tags: c#, string, format, numeric

Is it possible to apply multiple formatting simultaneously to a double?

For example, I want something like this

```
double d = 1234.567;
string format = ? 
// sig digit 4 , digit after decimal 4 , format = combination of G4 and F4 , G4F4?
d.toString(format) => "1235.0000"
```

Here, "G4" limits the significant digits to 4 and "F4" determines the number of digits after decimal point.

I know it is possible by using 2 separate format

```
Double.Parse((1234.567).ToString("G4")).ToString("F4") => "1235.0000"
```

Some more example

```
//sig digit 3 , digit after decimal 0 , format = combination of G3 and F0
d.toString(format) => "1230"
//sig digit 8 , digit after decimal 8 , format = combination of G8 and F8
d.toString(format) => "1234.56700000"
//sig digit 1 , digit after decimal 1 , format = combination of G1 and F1
d.toString(format) => "1000.0"
```

Comment: What about this `var str = (1234.567m).ToString("0000.0000")`? It returns `"1234.5670"`  and returns `"0034.5670" for 34.567`

Comment: Please provide 5-10 sample inputs and the expected sample outputs for those inputs.

Comment: You are conflating two separate concerns here. One is **rounding** and the other is **format strings**. To get `1234.567` to output as `1000.0` you should **round** it then use a format string. To output it as `1234.56700000` you just need a format string.

Comment: I was curious to combine the "G" format as 1234.567.tostring("G1") can output 1000 (1E+03). Anyway, thanks for the comment, it's not possible in a single format string.

Answer (score 0):

Your format string doesn't really make any sense. Significant digits can be before or after the decimal point; you're trying to specify two overlapping and contradictory formats simultaneously.

I think you are looking for: `ToString("0.0000")`

Comment: Thanks, I think it's not possible with single format statement.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is about [*Standard Numeric Format Strings*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings), then you should follow its specifications, else you will get a `FormatException` as noted at the end of table:

> Any other single character | Unknown specifier | Result: Throws a `FormatException` at run time.

---

What about using an extension method like this:

```
public static string ToString(this double value, int sig)
{
    return double.Parse(value.ToString($"G{sig}")).ToString($"F{sig}");
}
```